# Bundle of Transactions

Tags: bsc, cpp-ethereum, mev

I have been studying some articles about MEVs on the Ethereum network and met FlashBots which provides security for MEV Bots

[image]

That is a bundle propagation service which receives bundles from searchers and forwards them to miners on Ethereum.

> Searchers send Flashbots "bundles" to MEV-Relay. A bundle contains one or several transactions that can be the trader's and/or other users' pending transactions from the mempool, and fees for a bundle can be paid by the searcher via a smart contract call to block.coinbase.transfer()

and if none of the transactions in the bundle fail then forwards them on to miners.

Is it possible to use the same bundle execution mechanics in the BSC network? (I know diff between PoSA and PoW but I'd like to know if exist any similar process of bundle)

Comment: Did you get an answer to your questions somewhere else ? Best regards
Michael

Answer (score 1):

It is currently impossible to send bundles to BSC network.
On Ethereum network, it is possible because Ethereum implemented proposer-builder separation principle.
But at the moment, on BSC, there is no support for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Bloxroute supports sending bundle on BSC now https://docs.bloxroute.com/apis/mev-solution/bsc-bundle-submission